# How do I test a private method inside a setter c#

Tags: c#, testing

I am experiencing an issue during Testing.  I have a class and properties like these ones

```
 public class ViewModel {

 ....

   public string Person 
    {
        get
        {
            return _person;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_person != value)
            {
                _person = value;
                RefreshStrategy();
                OnPropertyChanged();
                Somefield = string.Empty;
            }
        }
    }

   public BindingList<string> Strategies
    {
        get
        {
            return _lstStrategies;
        }
    }
```

Now RefreshStrategy, which is a huge method with several other objects,  takes some strategies from a database and updates _lstStrategies according to the Person selected. Now everything is working fine on runtime but when I try to test it, I have an issue:

```
[TestClass]
public class ViewModelTest 
{

    private ViewModel _viewobj; 

    public ViewModelTest()
    {

        _viewobj = new ViewModel();
    }


    [TestMethod]
    public void TestStrategies()
    {
       _viewobj.Person = "Test";

        Assert.AreEqual("AAAA", _viewobj.Strategies[0]); 

    }

 private void RefreshStrategies()
    {
         Logger.log(Logger.INFO, $"GOT STRATEGIES");
        // Reload these default options every time the form loads, in case    some applications settings have been changed
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Trader) && !SettingsMgr.IsCompositePortfolio)
        {
            Person = Utility.SettingsMgr.PORTFOLIO_CODE;
        }
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Person))
        {

            string fund = _portfolios.Where((tt) => tt.PersonId == Person).Select(tt => tt.Fund).FirstOrDefault();
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fund))
            {
                fund = "X";
            }
            var profitCenters = new List<ProfitCenter>();
            try
            {
                Logger.log(Logger.INFO, $"Try to load strategies for {Person} {fund}");

                var pci = DataMgr.getInstance().GetProfitCenterInfo(Person, fund);
                Logger.log(Logger.INFO, $"HERE !!!");
                profitCenters = pci?.profitCenters;

            }
             ......

      }
```

When I set `Person = "Test"`, obviously `RefreshStrategy()` is called but inside all objects are null and it raises the exception "...attempt to dereference a null object reference".  The simple Logger at the beginning is raising and if I comment it out Utility.Setting is reasing and so on

If I do a trivial test on this class like testing a simple variable is passing and this is telling me that all references in the test project are fine.

What am I doing wrong? Do I mock the entire method? And if yes how if it is private?

Comment: Please post the RefreshStrategy function.

Comment: Move `RefreshStrategy` into separate class. Create interface for it and then you can simply mock the interface.

Comment: @Nkosi my question is to understand if I need to mock it or it is null because I am missing something during test

Comment: @Nkosi I will try to reproduce it in a small example.

Answer (score 1):

This is one way to go:

```
public interface IStrategyManager 
{
    void RefreshStrategy();
}
public class StrategyManager : IStrategyManager
{
    public void RefreshStrategy()
    {
         // Doesn't matter what is in here.
    }
}
public class ViewModel {
    public IStrategyManager StrategyManager = new StrategyManager();

   public string Person 
    {
        get
        {
            return _person;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_person != value)
            {
                _person = value;
                StrategyManager.RefreshStrategy();
                OnPropertyChanged();
                Somefield = string.Empty;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You just need to mock the property:

```
private ViewModel _viewModel;

[Test]
public void Test()
{
    _viewModel = new ViewModel
    {
        StrategyManager = new Mock<IStrategyManager>().Object,
        Person = "whatever"
    };

}
```

Of course it would work even better with `Dependency Injection`, but I don't know if you are using it. Then you could replace property with constructor injection.

This also allows you to have different implementations of `IStrategyManager`, which is nice. The weak point of this approach is additional class and interface.